# Change the appearance of the section and subsection of the TOC of an epub tex4epub tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

I hope that @michal.h21 can help me.
I tried your solution which works well, but I did not mention that the section and subsections too are modified.

I generalized the situation with the following example and I expose the problem in the picture
[image]

the problems are

- the vertical alignment is broken  with the sections and subsections

this is the `.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,sections+}

\NewSection\subsubsubsection{\theparagraph}


\Configure{section}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg<section id="section.\thesection">}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg</section>}
{\HCode{<font size="+0">}%
 \NoFonts\HCode{<span class="it">}%
 \TitleMark%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}}%
{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts%
 \HCode{</font>}%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}%
 \par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar%
}
\ConfigureMark{section}{\thesection~@@@~}

\Configure{subsection}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg<subsection id="subsection.\thesubsection">}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg</subsection>}
{\HCode{<font size="+0">}%
 \NoFonts\HCode{<span class="it">}%
 \TitleMark%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}}%
{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts%
 \HCode{</font>}%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}%
 \par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar%
}
\ConfigureMark{subsection}{\thesubsection~@@@~}



\Configure{subsubsection}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg<subsubsection id="subsubsection.\thesubsubsection">}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg</subsubsection>}
{\HCode{<font size="+0">}%
 \NoFonts\HCode{<span class="it">}%
 \TitleMark%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}}%
{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts%
 \HCode{</font>}%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}%
 \par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar%
}
\ConfigureMark{subsubsection}{\thesubsubsection~@@@~}



\Configure{subsubsubsection}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg<subsubsubsection id="subsubsubsection.\theparagraph">}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg</subsubsubsection>}
{\addtocounter{paragraph}{1}
 \HCode{<font size="+0">}%
 \NoFonts\HCode{<span class="it">}%
 \TitleMark%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}}%
{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts%
 \HCode{</font>}%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}%
 \par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar%
}
\ConfigureMark{subsubsubsection}{\theparagraph~@@@~}
\Configure{toToc}{subsubsubsection}{paragraph}


\Css{span.it{font-style:italic;}}
\ConfigureMark{subsubsubsection}{\theparagraph~@@@~}
\Configure{toToc}{subsubsubsection}{paragraph}


\ConfigureToc{paragraph}
{~~~\HCode{<span class="paragraphToc" >}}{~@@@~}{}{\HCode{</span>}\HCode{<br />\Hnewline}}

% \ConfigureToc{subsubsubsection}
% {~~~\HCode{<span class="subsubsubsectionToc" >}}{~@@@~}{}{\HCode{</span>}\HCode{<br />\Hnewline}}

\def\newncxtox#1#2{%
  \ConfigureToc{#1}%
  {\closelevels{#2}%
  \csname a:NavSection\endcsname\csname Ncx:Mark\endcsname}
  {\csname c:NavSection\endcsname~@@@~}
  {}
  {\csname b:NavSection\endcsname%
    \finishtoclevel{#1}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\def\csname ncx:title\endcsname{%
  \HCode{<docTitle>\Hnewline<text>}\Title\HCode{</text>\Hnewline</docTitle>\Hnewline}
\newncxtox{section}{section}
\newncxtox{subsection}{subsection}
\newncxtox{subsubsection}{subsubsection}
\newncxtox{paragraph}{paragraph}
\newncxtox{subparagraph}{subparagraph}
}
\EndPreamble
```

this is the tex file

```
    \documentclass{article} 

\makeatletter
\def\subsubsubsection{%
\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0em}{0.1\parskip}{1em}{}
}
\makeatother


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{first seciton}
    \subsection{first subsection}
    \subsubsection{first subSUBsection}
    \subsubsubsection{first subSUBsubsection}

    my subsubsubsection here

    \paragraph{first para}

\subsection{AA subsection}
    \subsubsection{AA subSUBsection}
    \subsubsubsection{AA subSUBsubsection}

    my subsubsubsection here

    \paragraph{AA para}

    werfj


    \section{second seciton}
    \subsection{second subsection}
    \subsubsection{second subSUBsection}
    \subsubsubsection{second subSUBsubsection}

    my subsubsubsection here

    \paragraph{second para}


\subsection{AA subsection}
    \subsubsection{AA subSUBsection}
    \subsubsubsection{AA subSUBsubsection}

    my subsubsubsection here

    \paragraph{AA para}


    werfj

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `newncxtox` must contain all subdivisions of the configured section level. This is needed in order to get the correct hierarchy in your `NCX` table of contents. The problem in your example isn't the spacing, but the fact that your subsequent sections and subsections are printed on the same level as `subsubsubsections`.

You need to change in this way:

```
\newncxtox{section}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\newncxtox{subsection}{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}    
\newncxtox{subsubsection}{subsubsection} 
\newncxtox{paragraph}{paragraph}    
\newncxtox{subparagraph}{subparagraph}
```

[image]